# How to solve the error while performing STORE operation in Pig?

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

I tried to execute a store operation in pig hdfs mode but it is throwing me the following error message

> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionenginemapreduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher-Failed.

I checked with the dump operation but it too gave me the same error

start-dfs.sh

start-yarn.sh
pig

> A = LOAD '/home/hduser/sample.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') as (ID:int, Name:chararray, .......) ;
>
> B = FOREACH A GENERATE ID, NAME
> STORE B INTO '/home/hduser' USING PigStorage(' ');

script for STORE and DUMP operation.

Comment: You would probably need to check the corresponding job(s) that was submitted by pig.  Also log file may contain some info. ([main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: ...)